# Lodash _.find using variable in argument dont work

Tags: javascript, find, lodash

When i search using the value hardcoded ("RHID||'-'||NOME") it works.

But when i use a variable (prop) it doesn't work.

This is a strange behaviour. It is a bug ?
I'm using lodash 3.10.

I apreciate very much your help. Thanks in advance

```
 var arr=[

      {
        "RHID||'-'||NOME": "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes",
        "VAL": "CMIP@3313@1987-01-05",
        "OTHERVALUES": "400@1900-01-01@200@1900-01-01"
      },

    ]
    var prop="RHID||'-'||NOME"

    console.log(_.find(arr, {prop: "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes"}))

    console.log(_.find(arr, {"RHID||'-'||NOME": "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes"}))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nxgfy7fp/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you search for `{prop: "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes"}` you are looking for a property named `prop`, and not the value of the variable `prop`.

You can use ES6's [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to make the variable work:

```js
var arr = [

  {
    "RHID||'-'||NOME": "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes",
    "VAL": "CMIP@3313@1987-01-05",
    "OTHERVALUES": "400@1900-01-01@200@1900-01-01"
  },

]
var prop = "RHID||'-'||NOME"

console.log(_.find(arr, {
  [prop]: "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes"
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

If the computed property names feature is not supported by your target browsers, use the old brackets notation to set the property value.

```js
var arr = [
  {
    "RHID||'-'||NOME": "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes",
    "VAL": "CMIP@3313@1987-01-05",
    "OTHERVALUES": "400@1900-01-01@200@1900-01-01"
  }
]
var prop = "RHID||'-'||NOME"
var search = {};
search[prop] = "3313-Abilio Dias Fernandes";

console.log(_.find(arr, search));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```